# Tag a Class object containing a list

Tags: c#, class, object, tags

I have a Class Student with

string wholeName;
List < int > scoresList;

I compiled an object students from text boxes into this:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        if (IsValidData())
        { 
            List<string> result = txtScores.Text.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            Student student = new Student(txtName.Text,  result.Select(int.Parse).ToList());
            this.Tag = student;
            this.Close();
        }
```

On the Form1 side I have this:

```
    private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewStudent addStudentForm = new AddNewStudent();
        DialogResult selectedButton = addStudentForm.ShowDialog();
        addStudentForm.Tag = new Student();
        if (selectedButton == DialogResult.OK)
           student = addStudentForm.Tag as Student;
        students.Add(student);

    }
```

I should be taking the Tag from the user information in the other form to construct a Student student and passing it back to Form1 and adding it to my students collection. Once it's added it should function like my manually created students when the form is loaded. Instead the list is null during runtime. Can I even move an entire object that contains a list through the Tag and if I can where did I go wrong?

Comment: You've given us the expected result, but what actually happens?

Comment: The tag was empty because I overrided it with an empty Tag with this "addStudentForm.Tag = new Student();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overiding Tag value in  addStudentForm.Tag = new Student(); line

Comment: Now, any idea why it's not being added to my actual collection?